# FF Neural network and binary classification

Tags: neural-network, classification, regression, feed-forward

Whenever I train a FeedForward neural network on a binary classification problem, the net returns float values. What's the theory behind this? Can this be interpreted as a probability? For instance, if the net returns 0.7 is that equivalent of saying that there's a 70% probability that the value is 1 and not 0? So should I just scale the float values and define a threshold to be either 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a sigmoid function as your activation function?

It will return values in that range. When u was playing around with mine, I treated it as a percentage of some arbitrary range. It can be a binary result though if you can tolerate a little bit of error. When I was training logic gates, after a fairly successful training session, 1 AND 1 resulted in something like 0.9999999; which is pretty much 1. You can round it at point that.

I made a post about this a month or two ago. I'll link to it if I can find it.

[My question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/289622/139925)

Comment: I see... So in short I should definitely play around with a threshold to change it from float values to binary output (and perhaps think of it as a percentage)?

Comment: I never used an explicit threshold. Each layer had a bias node, so the threshold was automatically handled as a weight, then I used backpropagation to train it.

Comment: +Luis I never used an explicit threshold. Each layer had a bias node, so the threshold was automatically handled as a weight, then I used backpropagation to train it.

Comment: +Luis If you want non-float activations, switch to a step function instead of a sigmoid function (again, assuming you're using a sigmoid).

Answer (score 0):

When you train a NN on a binary problem, if you don't use a binary activation function, the answer is going to be a probability (if you use a sigmoid): the instance probability to belong to a class.

I never use a threshold or binary activation function, because it is always interesting to study the probabilities. For example, you can have a misclassified instance, but you observe that its probability is around 0.5. Therefore the NN is not sure about the class to pin on the instance. At the opposite, if an instance is misclassified and has a strong probability (close to 0 or 1), then it is a strong error and you should seriously understand why it is misclassified.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)